# Show that $Z^{\prime }\left( s\right) -2\sqrt{-1}H\left( s\right) Z\left( s\right) -1=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider the equations

> > $2H\left( s\right) y\left( s\right) -x^{\prime }\left( s\right) -x^{\prime
> > \prime }\left( s\right) y\left( s\right) y^{\prime }\left( s\right)
> > +x^{\prime }\left( s\right) y\left( s\right) y^{\prime \prime }\left(
> > s\right) =0$
> >
> > $x^{\prime }\left( s\right) ^{2}+y^{\prime }\left( s\right) ^{2}=1$
> >
> > $Z\left( s\right) =y\left( s\right) y^{\prime }\left( s\right) +\sqrt{-1}%
> > y\left( s\right) x^{\prime }\left( s\right) $

where $H,x,y:I\rightarrow 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
$ are functions real of one variable

> > Show that
> >     $Z^{\prime }\left( s\right) -2\sqrt{-1}H\left( s\right) Z\left( s\right) -1=0
> > $, $s\in I\subset \mathbb{R}$

I have opened the accounts anyway, but can not show the equality of the differential equation.

Comment: Can you go back a few steps and tell more about the genesis of this problem? The first equation seems to tell something about $\arg(y'+ix)$, the second says that $|y'+ix|=1$ while $Z$ is a multiple of that complex number,...

Comment: It is a problem of rotational surfaces where $H$ is the mean curvature of the surfaces generated by the curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose coordinates are $x$ and $y$ in the plane $z = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your equations you get
$$
1=(y'+ix')(y'-ix')\\
0=x'x''+y'y''
$$
So for the function under consideration, $Z=y(y'+ix')$, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{Z'}{Z}&=\frac{y'}{y}+\frac{y''+ix''}{y'+ix'}
\\&
=\frac{y'}y+(y''+ix'')(y'-ix')
=\frac{y'}y+i(x''y'-y''x')
\\&
=\frac1y\left[y'+i(2Hy-x')\right]
\\
\implies Z'&
=\frac{Z}{y(y'+ix')}+2iHZ=1+2iHZ
\end{align}
which is indeed the given differential equation.